# Check if a user already voted

Tags: php, ip

I'm writing a Wordpress poll system. I need to check if a user already voted, show him/her a message. But i dont know exactly how can i do that!
One of my solutions is that to creating a table (named wp_voters) and entering each user's ip and poll id.

```
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

But it doesn't realy work. For a single user, It assigns two or more ip addresses.
How can i handle this problem?
thanks,

Comment: Why don't you ask your users to login before voting. If that's possible then you can simply add voters info in user meta and get the info from there when ever you want.

Comment: In my website, All users should be able to vote, even those that are not logged in.

Comment: Oh I see. In that case you can use the approach I have discussed in my answer below.

Comment: You definitely should additionally set cookies - containing information: voted for post with id, I'd suggest -  on voting - and use them for checking too -, because the IP will change, but the cookies might - as long as they are not deleted or it is another pc - stay much longer. One more note, if is is critical/important that the voting can't be abused neither IP or COOKIE checks - or both - are sufficient, then a login based system is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a table for such functionality in [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/) is not an efficient move. I would prefer to do this using follwoing approach.

1. Create [Custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) for your voters info. For this you can try [Generate WP post type generator](http://generatewp.com/post-type/).
2. When ever user visits your site; save IP and rating in [post meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) using [`wp insert post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) and [`add_post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta). In this way you will be able to view the list in back-end as well.
3. Every time when user visits your site check if there is some user with that IP using [WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). If it exist no need to add info else add his info using step 2.

Here is a simple function to get ip of your user;

```
function get_the_user_ip() {

    if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) ) {
    //check ip from share internet
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {
    //to check ip is pass from proxy
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    return $ip;

}
```

Hope this might work for you.

Comment: Glad to know! :)